# How do I bind a css class to a button in vue using or?

Tags: vue.js

What is the correct syntax for or in vue js v-bind:class?

```
<a class="button btn btn-default is-info" style="float:right;" v-on:click="clearSearchItem" v-bind:class="{'disabled': searchItem=='' || 'disabled': category==''}">Clear</a>
```

I basically want to say disable this button if searchItem=="" or category==""

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<a class="button btn btn-default is-info" style="float:right;" v-on:click="clearSearchItem" v-bind:class="{'disabled': searchItem=='','disabled': category==''}">Clear</a>
```

How do I bind a css class to a button in vue using or?

**Update - Solution**

```
v-bind:class="{'disabled': !(searchItem || category)}"
```

Comment: use `:class="{ 'disabled': searchItem === '' || cat === '' }"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can have 2 of the same class in one object. You can try

`v-bind:class="{'disabled': !(searchItem || category)}"`

or

`:class="{'disabled': !(searchItem || category)}"`

This basically saying that if one of the searchItem and category is empty or null the disable class is true.

JavaScript read empty string as false so you do not need to add `== '' or === ''`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:class="(searchItem == '' || category == '') ? 'disabled' : ''}"
```

Read more from this [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html).